# Numerical solution of PDE using the Shooting Method; implementation and errors

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I want to solve numerically using the shooting method the following PDE (I am using the shooting method because from everything I read I think it fits better to the problem, however I haven't done much work on numerical solutions of PDE's and if you have alternative suggestions, please let me know.)

$$\partial_r(r^5 \sin^3 \theta_B \partial_r \theta) + \partial_x(r \sin^3 \theta_B \partial_x \theta)- r^3(3 \cos^2\theta_B \sin \theta_B - \frac{3}{2} \sin^2 \theta_B) \theta = 0$$

where of course $\theta=\theta(r,x)$

with

$$\theta_B = \cos^{-1}(\frac{m}{r})$$

and with the conditions

$$\theta(m,x)= 1$$
$$\partial_{r}\theta(m,x) =0$$

This is the code.

```
\[Theta]B[r_] := ArcCos[m/r]

diffeq = D[r^5 Sin[\[Theta]B[r]]^3 D[\[Theta][r, x], r], r] + 
   D[r Sin[\[Theta]B[r]]^3 D[\[Theta][r, x], x], x] - 
   r^3 (3 Cos[\[Theta]B[r]]^2 Sin[\[Theta]B[r]] - 
      3/2 Sin[\[Theta]B[r]]^2) \[Theta][r, x] == 0

 nsolone = NDSolve[\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(r\)]\((
\*SuperscriptBox[\(r\), \(5\)]\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(Sin[\[Theta]B[r]]\), \(3\)] 
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(r\)]\ r\ \[Theta][r, x])\)\) + \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\((r\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(Sin[\[Theta]B[r]]\), \(3\)]\ 
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\ \((r\ \[Theta][r, x])\))\)\) -
      r^3 (3 Cos[\[Theta]B[r]]^2 Sin[\[Theta]B[r]] - 
        3/2 Sin[\[Theta]B[r]]^2) r \[Theta][r, x] == 0, 
   r \[Theta][r, x] , {r, m, 10}, {x, 1, 10}, 
   Method -> {"Shooting", 
     "StartingInitialConditions" -> { r \[Theta][m, x] == 1,  \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(r\)]\((r\ \[Theta][r, x])\)\) /. 
        r -> m == 0}}] /. Assumptions -> m \[Element] Reals
```

Question1: I think I have implemented correctly the PDE, but if you spot any mistakes let me know.

Question2: I have made the assumption that $m \in \mathbf{R}$ and Mathematica returns the following error.

```
NDSolve::ndnl: Endpoint m in {r,10.,m} is not a real number.
```

And I do not understand why.

I would appreciate any suggestions/corrections.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error is just telling you that you have to set $m$ equal to an actual number before `NDSolve` can do anything;  numerical methods don't work with symbolic input.  If you set $m = 1$ or $m = 7$ or $m = \pi$ before running your code, it executes fine.  (No guarantees that the equations are correct, though.)

Comment: Thank you for that. I am performing another calculation, but I will try it and report back.

Comment: Hi Michael, I set m to a constant value as you suggested and it does not work properly. 

If you have the time to check, here it is:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165242/numerical-solution-to-pde-using-the-shooting-method-and-plot

Cheers!!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.

Answer (score 3):

Rewriting your code as

```
With[{m = 1},
    θB[r_] := ArcCos[m/r];
    NDSolve[
      D[r^5Sin[θB[r]]^3*D[r, r]θ[r,x], r] +
        D[r Sin[θB[r]]^3 D[r θ[r, x], x], x] - 
          r^3(3Cos[θB[r]]^2Sin[θB[r]]-(3/2)Sin[θB[r]]^2)r θ[r, x] == 0,
      r θ[r, x], {r, m, 10}, {x, 1, 10},
      Method->
        {"Shooting", 
         "StartingInitialConditions" -> 
          {r θ[m,x]==1,D[r θ[r,x],r] /. r -> m == 0}}]]
```

gives

[image: results]

which represents progress if not a complete answer to your problem. Perhaps you can move forward using this answer as a base.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, however, I posted another question yesterday

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165242/numerical-solution-to-pde-using-the-shooting-method-and-plot

where I get only the second error. 

When I try to understand what this error means I cannot, since -as I explained in the other topic- it just opens the site with the generic info on differential equations. 

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html

It's not that I am too lazy to read about the error and fix it. I don't have any sources for that.