# Numerical solution to PDE using the shooting method and plot.

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration

This is related to: [Numerical solution of PDE using the Shooting Method; implementation and errors](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165215/numerical-solution-of-pde-using-the-shooting-method-implementation-and-errors)

which I asked earlier today. I realised what I did wrong, I fixed it, but I still get errors.

This is what I want to do.

I want to solve numerically using the shooting method the following PDE (I am using the shooting method because from everything I read I think it fits better to the problem, however, I haven't done much work on numerical solutions of PDE's and if you have alternative suggestions, please let me know.)

$$\partial_r(r^5 \sin^3 \theta_B \partial_r \theta) + \partial_x(r \sin^3 \theta_B \partial_x \theta)- r^3(3 \cos^2\theta_B \sin \theta_B - \frac{3}{2} \sin^2 \theta_B) \theta = 0$$

where of course $\theta=\theta(r,x)$

with

$$\theta_B = \cos^{-1}(\frac{m}{r})$$

and with the conditions

$$\theta(m,x)= 1$$
$$\partial_{r}\theta(m,x) =0$$

and then plot the solution.

This is the code.

```
\[Theta]B[r_, m_] := ArcCos[m/r]

nsolone = NDSolve[\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(r\)]\((
\*SuperscriptBox[\(r\), \(5\)]\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(Sin[\[Theta]B[r, 1]]\), \(3\)] 
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(r\)]\[Theta][r, x])\)\) + \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\((r\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(Sin[\[Theta]B[r, 1]]\), \(3\)]\ 
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\ \[Theta][r, x])\)\) - 
    r^3 (3 Cos[\[Theta]B[r, 1]]^2 Sin[\[Theta]B[r, 1]] - 
       3/2 Sin[\[Theta]B[r, 1]]^2) \[Theta][r, x] == 0, \[Theta][r, 
   x] , {r, 1, 10^7}, {x, 0, 10^7}, 
  Method -> {"Shooting", 
    "StartingInitialConditions" -> {\[Theta][1, 0] == 1,  \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(r\)]\((\[Theta][1, 0])\)\) == 0}}]
```

This is the error that I am getting.

```
NDSolve::femibcnd: No DirichletCondition or Robin-type NeumannValue was specified for {\[Theta]}; the result is not unique up to a constant.
```

When I try to study the error in order to fix it, this opens with the very generic info on D.E's. 
http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html

And I do not have any idea how to plot this.

Thanks!!!

Comment: What you call an error is only a hint `result is not unique up to a constant`. You can plot the solution with `Plot3D[\[Theta][r, x] /. nsolone[[1]], {r, 1, 10^7}, {x, 0, 10^7}]` but solution unfotunately appears to be zero. Perhaps with additional boundary conditions you can force unique solution?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will give it a go. Cheers!!!